# Questions in localization of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

This question was left as an exercise in my class of Algebraic Geometry and unfortunately I am not very good in solving problems of Localization. I have been following my class notes.

So, I am posting it here in hope of getting some guidance.

> Question: Let $P\in Spec A$ , where $A$ is a ring and $Spec A$ is Spectrum of $A$, $S= A\setminus P$ is multiplicatively closed.  Define , $S^{-1} A= A_P$ . Prove that $\{P A_P\} =   Spm A_P$ (where $Spm A_P$ is the max spectrum) and $A_P / P A_P =  Q(A/P)$, where $Q(A/P)$ is ring of quotients of $A/P$.

Attempt: For 1st, 1 way is proving by taking an element from set in LHS and proving it into RHS and also converse. But I am looking for an elegant method for both parts and unfortunately I am totally struck on them.

I understand the theory taught in class, but not able to make progress. Can you please give a few hints?

Edit: I found solution of 1st part here:[Why is the localization at a prime ideal a local ring?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300446/why-is-the-localization-at-a-prime-ideal-a-local-ring)

Comment: No problem: but there were still a few corrections to be made. You must really distinguish between $A/P$ and $A\setminus P$. I've set them straight now.

Comment: The fact that localizing at the complement of a prime ideal always produces a ring with a single maximal ideal is probably in multiple places on the site and in every commutative algebra reference.  The other half might be more novel.

Comment: @rschwieb So, can you please write an  answer for this?

Comment: I haven’t really seen sufficient attempt on your part yet to know how to help you.  I would help you get unstuck with the second half, if I knew where you were stuck.

Comment: @rschwieb I am struck on 2nd part also, can you please help with that?